# React: is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

When I refresh the error message in clearAll() is:

./src/App.js

Line 22:  'notes' is not defined  no-undef

Line 23:  'notes' is not defined  no-undef

How do I define the the properties to use>

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Route from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Router from './components/Router';
import Home from '.Home';
import AddNote from '/AddNote';
import EditNote from '/EditNote';


class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        note: "",
        notes: []
    };
}

clearAll() {
    notes.length = 0;
    notes = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`note` and `notes` are saved on the component's state, you can access them in your component via `this.state.note` and `this.state.notes` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

const { note, notes } = this.state;

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this answers the question. Answers that are little more than a line of code are not very useful for those who might come across the same or a similar issue later on.